Compile vs Runtime Binding
I have java code. In first example, it is said that compile time binding is here, But in second example,
 class Animal {
    void sound() {
        System.out.println("Animal makes a sound");
    }
}
class Dog extends Animal {
    @Override
    void sound() {
        System.out.println("Dog barks");
    }
}
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal animal = new Dog();
        animal.sound(); // Output: "Animal makes a sound"
    }
}

It is said that here is runtime binding,
class Shape {
    void draw() {
        System.out.println("Drawing a shape");
    }
}
class Circle extends Shape {
    @Override
    void draw() {
        System.out.println("Drawing a circle");
    }
}class Square extends Shape {
    @Override
    void draw() {
        System.out.println("Drawing a square");
    }
}public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Shape shape1 = new Circle();
        Shape shape2 = new Square();        shape1.draw(); // Output: "Drawing a circle"
        shape2.draw(); // Output: "Drawing a square"
    }
}

I am unable to identify the difference, Can someone please help here?

First one is also runtime or dynamic binding.

In first example, it is said Please identify the source. Can you add an elaborate quote (including some context) what exactly is said there?
